# "Add new item"-button appears as visited link

Tags: list

The "add new item"-button for my Sharepoint 2010 list appears as visited (purple) when I have used it. My question is simple: How do I get this to show in ordinary blue color and not indicate the recent use of it?

[Image of the purple "add new item"-button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6UaEu.png)

Comment: maybe you could put a custom css class for `.ms-addnew:visited { color:#0e357a }` ?

Comment: Steve, I haven't checked if the property is correct, but in any case this I think is the correct answer. You should put it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

delete your browsing history..